# Strange symbol on circuit diagram

Tags: circuit-design, symbol

I am trying to reverse-engineer some circuit diagrams. I have found some symbols on there that I've never seen before. I can't seem to find anything on Google. It looks like two terminal connectors being connected to eachother. Below is a picture of this specific symbol.[image: two unknown symbols]

[image: Bigger overview of component]

Comment: Maybe a normally closed switch? What's the context?

Comment: Or possibly some kind of link (solder, wire, jumper, etc.)  If you have or can find a photo of the physical item, that will likely answer the question.

Comment: Could we see (a lot) more of your schematic?

Comment: Perhaps tell us more about the circuit? what are these connected to?

Comment: @Lundin There are about 6 of these in series, without any components between them (2 of which are inside the 'Paal 2' device and 2 outside of the 'Paal 2'. This 'Paal 2' device has a single switch inside, switching other circuits on and off. Really not that much going on actually.

Comment: @Tyler I am unfortunately not able to show you a lot more about the schematic due to privacy issues. See my reply on Lundin's comment for more context.

Comment: Is this a PCB schematic or and electrical schematic?

Comment: Google Translate says the Dutch word “Paal” is “Pole”, does that sound correct? Is this some sort of relay?

Comment: There are 6 in series, ok. But what are those 6 connected to?

Comment: @Tyler It indeed is a pole. It's a pole with a switch inside. And a few of these weird unknown symbols. It's not a relay. One wire going into the pole, and one wire coming out of the pole. Guessing by the way I caused this confusion, I think I can conclude this not being a conventional symbol haha. It is an electrical schematic, not a pcb design. I should remove that hastag.

Comment: It does seem to be a closed switch. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze7Rk.png) is the open version. I can't be sure because I have no idea about the numbers underneath. And, on its own, placing two of them in series makes no sense. So it's better two see the full image or at least the surrounding, where it connects to, etc.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I updated my post with a bigger overveiw, just within company rules. A switch would make no sense as you said. S6 and S7 are redundant switches, for safety reasons.

Comment: A and C are recurring. It's not far-fetched to guess they mean Anode and Cathode. I wouldn't name + and - of a polarised relay for anode/cathode... So... LEDs? Batteries? Or connectors for them?

Comment: From the symbol I'd have said it's a gas discharge tube (lamp or overvoltage protection). Reed relais seems to be ruled out already (which would have a contact painted intu the shape anyway).

Comment: Looks pretty professional, there isn’t a lead sheet with symbols / meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the numbers mean length and they're using this design to do some kind of phase matching or length matching. Especially if this is some kind of RF design.

Another possibility is that they are doing current measurements they could change the resistivity

Comment: These numbers representing wire length could be very well possible. Since I know Paal 1 and Paal 2 are equal, the wires inside of these devices seem to be of equal length as well according to this diagram.